# Flutter widget inside grid view animation to next screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

If I create a home screen with a `GridView` of widgets containing images and descriptions, how could I make it so that when a user clicks on one of the widgets, the image in that widget animates over to the next screen? For example, if I have a chat app where users could chat with any other user they select in the `GridView`, the image from that selected widget would animate to the top of a chat screen for them to chat. I thought maybe this could be accomplished with a hero animation but I am not able to figure it out since the image widget would be nested inside a widget and then inside a `GridView`. It would be easy to pass the image URL through to the chat screen, which I may have to do, but I think the animation would make the UI flow much better. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, just make sure the hero tags between the two routes/pages match and that on any given page all the hero tags are unique. I have the same where the hero animates from a grid view into the next page's app bar.